# How to align a value to a given alignment

Tags: c++, math

I have a value that I want to align to a given alignment, ie increase the value to the next multiple of the alignment if it is not already aligned.

What is a concise way to do this in C++?

eg

```
int x;
int alignment;
int y = ???; // align x to alignment
```

Comment: C++11 has `alignas`, if you can use that.

Comment: Just to be clear: you’re talking about *memory alignment* so you *do not* want to “increase the value” – you want to align the memory address of the object; is that right?

Comment: int y = x + (x % alignment == 0 ? 0 : alignment - x % alignment)

Comment: y = x + (a - x%a)... a = alignment

Comment: Yeah this is memory alignment but for some stuff I am writing to a file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Lets say alignment is `a`

```
---(k-1)a-----------x--------------ka---------
         <----r----><-----(a-r)--->
```

where `k` is an integer (so `ka` is a multiple of alignment)

First find the remainder

`r = x%a`

then increment x to next multiple

`y = x + (a-r)`

But if r = 0, then y = x

So finally

```
r = x%a;
y = r? x + (a - r) : x;
```

Comment: Instead of `y = r ? x + (a - r) : x`, you can also use `y = (x + a - 1) / a * a` which is more efficient if `a` is a constant of the form `1 << n` as the compiler can then rewrite this into something like `y = x + a - 1 & ~(a - 1)` which is better than a conditional.

Answer (score 4):

If the alignment is a power of 2, and the machine uses complement of 2 for negative numbers then:

```
mask = alignment - 1;
aligned_val = unaligned_val + (-unaligned_val & mask);
```

Answer (score 0):

From my snippets-library:

```
template <typename I=size_t>
inline I IntAlign( I sz, I step=16,  I min=16  ) {
  auto s = std::max(sz+step-1,min);
  return s - s%step;
}
```

It's simple enough math so...
Here's a fragment from the test-code:

```
TEST(Sz,Basic) {
  EXPECT_EQ( 16U, IntAlign(0U) );
  EXPECT_EQ( 16U, IntAlign(1U) );
  EXPECT_EQ( 8U, IntAlign(5U,8U,8U) );
  EXPECT_EQ( 8U,  IntAlign(7U,8U,8U) );
  EXPECT_EQ( 64U,  IntAlign(7U,8U,64U) );

  EXPECT_EQ( 16, IntAlign(0) );
  EXPECT_EQ( 16, IntAlign(1) );
  EXPECT_EQ( 8, IntAlign(8,8,8) );
  EXPECT_EQ( 8,  IntAlign(7,8,8) );
  EXPECT_EQ( 64,  IntAlign(7,8,64) );
}
```

> **Note!**
> Add tests from your use-case and fix it if need be.
> Nothing guaranteed!